# Backgroundworker progress: how can it report a double number instead of integer

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am developing a window application in VB.net and i as using backgroundworker.
Maybe it is a very simple question, but is it possible report the progress as a double number and not as the integer part of the progress percentage?

I need the full number in order to display some more info, and i can only do this when i know the exact iteration the algorithm is in.

Is there any easy way doing so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ReportProgress` method has two overloads.  The [first one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) takes only a `percentProgress As Integer` parameter, but the [second one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) takes an additional `userState As Object` parameter.  With that second overload, you can pass any type of data that you want.  In your case, you could pass a `Double` value as your user-state, like this

```
BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myDouble)
```

Then, in the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event handler, you can convert the value back to a `Double`, like this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim myDouble As Double = CDbl(e.UserState)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

As in the above example, if you don't need the `percentProgress` parameter, you can just pass a value of `0` for that parameter.  You are not limited to passing just one or two values either.  If you need to pass additional information, such as a status string, you could do so by creating your own class to encapsulate all of the status-related data and then pass one of those objects as your `userState` parameter.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyUserState
    Public Property MyDouble As Double
    Public Property StatusDescription As String
End Class
```

Then you could call the `ReportProgress` method like this:

```
Dim myState As New MyUserState()
myState.MyDouble = 1.1
myState.StatusDescription = "Test"
BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myState)
```

Then, you can read the values like this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim myState As MyUserState = DirectCast(e.UserState, MyUserState)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  If this answers your question, you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking the big check box next to this answer.